# Vue Js on conditional disable update v-model as well

Tags: vue.js

I want to update the v-model of the dropdown when its conditionally got disabled. Meaning I just want to reset my ir.IR_SectionId to 0 when the select box get disabled.

```
  <select v-model="ir.IR_SectionId" v-default-value:ir.IR_SectionId="0" 
  :disabled="ir.IR_SecurityTypeId <= 0">
  <option v-for="s in irSectionList" v-bind:value="s.Id">{{s.Name}}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: How does it get disabled? Is is set from the outside? or just when an option with a value <= 0 is selected?

Comment: there is another drop-down which has v-model=ir.IR_SecurityTypeId, when user select any option other > 0 in this dropdown then above select box get disabled. The variable ir is from the List which holds these Ids and iterate to create multiple rows with dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the **:disable** expression

```
<select v-model="ir.IR_SectionId" v-default-value:ir.IR_SectionId="0" 
  :disabled="isDisabled">
  <option v-for="s in irSectionList" v-bind:value="s.Id">{{s.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

> You can create a getter that updates its component to disabled and in
>   that case it would change the value of IR_SectionId to 0

```
getters: {
    isDisabled: () => {
      let disabled = this.ir.IR_SecurityTypeId <= 0
      if(disabled) this.ir.IR_SectionId = 0
      return disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put side effects in getters. Use a `watch` to reset `IR_SectionId`.